# how to solve this GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS problem in Firebase hosting with GitHub action CICD

Tags: firebase, vue.js, github, cicd

I have my Vuejs project which is hosted on Firebase hosting with GitHub actions CICD and correctly facing below error while deploying to Firebase

here is my build-and-deploy.yml code

```
  - name: Deploy to firebase
  uses: w9jds/firebase-action@v2.1.2
  with: 
    args: deploy 
  env: 
    FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
```

how can I use GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS  instead of FIREBASE_TOKEN
[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of FIREBASE_TOKEN, use the GCP_SA_KEY environment variable. According to the [docs](https://github.com/w9jds/firebase-action#environment-variables), it expects:

*A normal service account key (json format) or a base64 encoded service account key with the needed permissions for what you are trying to deploy/update.*

I hope that helps.